# Javascript getElemtsByClass select [all]

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to select all elements with the css class

```
.arrow-down
```

Sorry but i simply dont find the correct answer, for my problem!

I have an javascript code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("arrow-down")[0].style.borderTopColor=""+blu+"";
```

so how do i select not the first but [all] or is there a way to [1;2;3;]??

```
getElementsByClassName("arrow-down")[all]

getElementsByClassName("arrow-down")[1;2...]
```

I tried many things but simply dont get it!

Greetings from germany!

Comment: You don't know how to do a `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the list of returned results.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow-down");

for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++){
  elements[i].style.borderTopColor = blu;
}
```

If you want to only do a specific subset based on the index, then you can add a condition that checks the value of `i`. I'm also assuming that `blu` here is a variable you have defined somewhere?

```
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++){
  if (i === 1 || i === 2 || i === 3){
    elements[i].style.borderTopColor = blu;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, JavaScript does not have a shorthand for accessing a specific subset of array values, or for applying changes to multiple elements at once. That is something that jQuery does automatically for you. For instance, with jQuery you could write this as:

```
$('.arrow-down').css('borderTopColor', blu);
```

Comment: How do i add another variable to the    for (...                           for example :                                                         var element = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow-box");             d                                                                         for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++){
   elements[i].style.borderTopColor = blu;
   element[i].style.backgroundColor = blu;                                   but somehow this dont functions?

Comment: `for (var i = 0; len = elements.length;...` is the same as `var i = 0; var len = elements.length; for(;...` Is that what you mean?

Comment: @EmSta You have a stray `d` in your example code there. Also you have written `element` instead of `elements`.

Comment: @EmSta Your `element` if a whole separate list of elements, you should iterate over it with a separate loop, since it might not be the same length. You are also missing an ending `}`.

Comment: the missing } is because i copied it, sorry! Actually it has the same lenght, so can i add the variable?

Comment: @EmSta I don't know what to say then, your code looks reasonable. Do you get any errors?

Comment: No but, forget about it, i will simply add a new loop! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName("arrow-down")` does select *all* of such elements.

These are returned in a node list (which can be treated as an array), which is why using `[0]` on that returns the first element.

Loop over the different elements that the expression returns and act on them:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow-down");
var elementsNum = elements.length)

for(var i = 0; i < elementsNum; i++)
{
  var anElement = elements[i];

  // do something with anElement
}
```

Comment: @Teemu - For explaining the issue, it might as well be an array. Does it really matter here?

Comment: It seems OP is just learning the basics, would be fear to tell him/her about the [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList)s?

Comment: +1, but of course it matters. And `.Length` should be `.length`

Comment: @Oded Yes, it makes a difference. For instance, you don't get all the array methods like `slice`.